# I have to syncronize a .csv file with a google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, synchronization, nas

I have to synchronize a .csv file with a google sheet. The csv file is stored into a NAS area with a specific path.

The final output is to have a google sheet file which is a copy of the csv file periodically updated. The purpose is to automate the process of updating a dashboard that has the google sheet as the database but the original source file is periodically issued in this NAS area.

Can you help me?

Comment: Sounds like it would work to me have you tried?

Comment: Not yet. I'm not a programmer so I need some inputs or materials/articles to start trying... Do you think I need to be a programmer to do smt like that?